# .sh stops execution after invoking a .py if run from Gnome shortcut

Tags: python, linux, bash, gnome

I have a dumb question and I hope you can help me ..
I have "script1.sh", "script_python.py" and "script_python2.py", all have permissions 755 and are in the same folder

script1.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

example=/path/to/script_python.py
arg=/path/to/image.jpg
variable=/path/to/script_python2.py
path_file=/path/to/file.webm
title_test="This is the title"
descripcion_test="This is the description"

python $example $arg $arg

python $variable --file="$path_file" --title="$title_test" --description="$descripcion_test" --category="22" --privacyStatus="public"
exit 0
```

Make a cd to the folder containing the scripts, then (from the bash console) write:

```
./script1.sh
```

It runs all OK! ..it runs perfect both python scripts

## ----------------------------------------

But the problem is here ...

If I create a shortcut 'gnome' (All Settings> Shortcuts> Keyboard) and income as /path/to/script1.sh command .....  runs the first python script('script_python.py')..but NOT run the 2nd python script ('script_python2.py')...

It means that fails to run 'script_python2.py' from 'script1.sh' when pressure key combination... why?
How could solve this problem?

Thanks you!

Comment: It's probably due to running from a different directory, but you've redacted the paths so it's hard to tell (consider redact->run->post instead of run->redact->post). Do you experience the same problem if you do `cd ~ && /full/path/to/script1.sh` instead of cd'ing and using `./`?

Comment: Are you sure you are not using a relative path?